# Problem with running maven on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, maven-3

I have downloaded maven binary zip archive and unzipped it. However when I go into terminal and enter apache-maven-3.6.3\bin directory and type mvn I am getting the following error:

zsh: command not found: mvn

I am a new user of MacOS, please help. I am also having trouble with setting JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: Try running `./mvn` instead.

Comment: you've already add Maven to the Environment Path?

Comment: No I haven't added Maven to Environment Path. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1.After downloading, extract it in a safe location with the following command.

```
$ tar -xvf apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz
```

Take note of the version number. Change it to the version you downloaded.

2.Setting Maven Environment Variables - `M2_HOME` and Path.

Next is to open .bash_profile in your root folder with your favorite text editor and copy the following below the file.

```
export M2_HOME="/Users/<YOUR-MAVEN-DOWNLOADED-LOCATION-HERE>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3"
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Save and close the file.

To Verify the Maven Installation, Open your terminal and change to root directory of the `.bash_file` by typing the following in terminal

```
source .bash_profile
```

Then run the following to confirm the Maven version.

```
mvn -version
```

That is all.